# How can I remove a deadbolt from an interior door and close the bore?

Tags: doors, lock

We have an interior door in our new (to us) home with a Schlage deadbolt that we want to remove. Is there a commercially available metal set-up with no keying?  Both door sides & strike plate... don't want to replace door.

Comment: you need to provide more information. we do not provide shopping advise. "commercially available metal set-up with no keying"  what does that mean?  add a detailed description and question if you want informed answers.

Comment: Why would there even be a deadbolt on an interior door? That said, I agree that this is a shopping question. @isherwood deadbolts keyed from the inside on _entry_ doors are being phased out as they are fire hazards, so I'd be wary of rekeying the existing deadbolt the OP has. Putting on a dummy plate is the way to go.

Comment: Is there a regular passage lock with knob or lever also in this door or is the deadbolt all there is?

Comment: My mistake. I missed that critical point when I read. I wonder if that was misstated, though. Why indeed would there be a deadbolt on an interior door. Jack, can you enlighten us?

Comment: kids who take their privacy seriously. Servers you don't want your kids messing with.  *The dungeon*.   Pot plants growing and you have too many guests, any of whom could invite a cop in.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a blank hole cover such as this:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-2-5-8-in-Satin-Nickel-Hole-Cover-Plate-U-10446/202258423
[image]

You can also get "blank strike plates" and "blank latch plates"

Answer (score 0):

Wood dowels can be cut to fill in the hole left by a removed deadbolt.  Painting is the only option to hide the mismatched grain.

Answer (score 0):

Could just remove the "bolt" part that moves in & out, and just leave the keyed lock & lever filling the hole in the door; no one could lock the door without the bolt but it would still look finished.